# How to run Help File?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I added a "Help.mht" file into my app Properties->Resource.

How to run the Help file when user press the Help button. Try using the following but not working.

```
Process.Start(My.Resources.Help)
```

thanks.

Comment: `Process.Start` does expect a command or path, you're giving him the content of the Help-File. Try extracting it into a temporary file first.

Comment: how do i do that? please provide some examples thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub Main()
  Dim name As String = "Help.mht"
  Dim dir = Application.StartupPath
  Dim path = Path.Combine(dir, name)

  If Not File.Exists(path) Then
    File.WriteAllBytes(path, My.Resources.Help)
  End If

  Process.Start(path)
End Sub
```

Comment: Two things: You can use `Application.StartupPath` or `Application.ExecutablePath` (non-VB-specific classes/namespaces). Second, please always use `[System.IO.]Path.Combine()` for concatenating paths.

Comment: @Bobby, +1 for the `Path.Combine suggestion`, the `Application.StartupPath` is win-forms specific. it won't work in WPF, the question is tagged vb.net, so there is no problem answering vb-specific answer, ITOH the post is not tagged with either win-forms, or WPF.

Comment: @Shimmy: Thanks for the info on `Application`, I didn't know that, but I'll keep it in mind.

Comment: @Shimmy: I'd *always* use it, just to be on the safe side. And you'll most likely never feel these internal functions (performance wise).

Comment: thanks for the help, i'm using Path.Combine() and yes i'm using it for VB (win-forms).